Proving that a subgroup of $G$ is a group in its own right
I'm trying to solve Problem 1.1.26 in Dummit and Foote's algebra book, but I think I'm getting lost in the weeds. The problem states:

Assume $H$ is a nonempty subset of $(G, \star)$ which is closed under the binary operation on $G$ and is closed under inverses, i.e., for all $h$ and $k \in H$, $hk$ and $h^{-1} \in H$. Prove that $H$ is a group under the operation $\star$ restricted to $H$ (such a subset $H$ is called a subgroup of $G$).

The four things I need to check are that $H$ is: closed under composition, has an associative operations, and contains the identity and inverses.

That $H$ is closed under composition is true from the assumption that $H$ is closed under the binary operation of $G$. This means that the restriction of $\star$ to $H \times H$ is a valid law of composition on $H$. I'll denote this operation by $\overline{\star}$.

Associativity is inherited from $(G, \star)$ since $\star$ and $\overline{\star}$ agree on elements of $H$.


The latter two conditions are what gave me the most confusion. As $H$ is nonempty, I can pick $h \in H$. The assumption then tells me that $h^{-1} \in H$. I can't tell whether this is the inverse of $h$ in $G$ or the inverse of $h$ in $H$. That is, I can't tell if this allows me to say:
$$
\exists h' \in H, \; hh' = 1_H = h'h \qquad (1)
$$
or
$$
\exists h'' \in H, \; hh'' = 1_G = h''h.
$$
The latter would imply, by uniqueness of inverses in $G$, that $H$ contains inverses and, by closure under composition, that $H$ contains the identity element of $G$, so the proof would be complete. I don't think that's right, however.
If I went with the former interpretation, I could say: $h$ has an inverse $h' \in H$, so by definition, $hh' = 1_H = h'h$, so $H$ has an identity. Regarded as elements of $G$ and using $h''$ to denote the inverse of $h$ in $G$, we have $hh' = hh''$, so cancelling $h$ on the right gives $h' = h''$. So I can say that $h'' \in H$, and since $H$ is closed under composition, $hh'' = 1_G \in H$ and $1_G = 1_H$.
I'm not completely sure how to interpret this prompt or whether my argument is in any way circular.

The element $h^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$ in $G$; but since it is also in $H$ and $H$ is closed under the operation, you know that because $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are both in $H$, so is $hh^{-1}=1_G$. So $H$ contains the identity of $G$. You can also note that if $1_H$ were an identity element for $H$ under $\star$, then $1_H\star 1_H=1_H$ is an equality that holds in $G$. But the only element $x$ in a group with $xx=x$ is the identity element, so if $H$ is to have an identity under $\star$, it better be the one from $G$. So both interpretations lead to the result (cont)

(cont) though the first is a bit incoherent because you do not yet know whether $H$ under the restriction of $\star$ has an identity. Though as I just noted, you can show that if it had an identity, it would have to be $1_G$, and hence you should go with your second interpretation.

A priori, it is the inverse $h_G^{-1}$ of $h$ in $G$ (since you're trying to prove $H$ is a group in its own right). But $H\subseteq G$ and, provably, $$h^{-1}_G=h^{-1}_H.$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
h_H^{-1}&=h_H^{-1}1_G & (\text{as }h_H^{-1}\in G)\\
&=h_H^{-1}(hh_G^{-1}) & (\text{by def.})\\
&=(h_H^{-1}h)h_G^{-1} & (\text{by assoc.})\\
&=(1_H)h_G^{-1} & (\text{by def.})\\
&=h_G^{-1}, & (\text{by Lem 1})
\end{align}$$
where

Lemma 1: Let $G$ be a group. Then $G$ had exactly one idempotent.

Proof: Let $x^2=x$. We have $e^2=e$. Now
$$\begin{align}
x&=ex\\
&=(x^{-1}x)x\\
&=x^{-1}x^2\\
&=x^{-1}x\\
&=e.\,\square
\end{align}$$
